# Is the Laplace Beltrami operator a uniformly elliptic operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The condition of uniform ellipticty for an operator $L=    (-1)^k\sum_{\alpha} a_\alpha(x)\partial^{\alpha}$  is expressed as the condition that:
$$    (-1)^k\sum_{|\alpha| = 2k} a_\alpha(x) \xi^\alpha > C |\xi|^{2k},\, $$

for every non-zero $\xi$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$

A usual example of these type of operators is the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator).

A natural generalization of the Laplacian in a Rimaniann manifold is the [Laplace-Beltrami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator) operator.

My question is:

What are the geometrical and regularity conditions on the metric such that the Laplace Beltrami operator is a strongly elliptic operator?